# How to integrate Gradle, IntelliJ, and SpotBugs?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, spotbugs

I have a Gradle project with subprojects and a somewhat complicated `build.gradle` file.  I imagine that running SpotBugs from Gradle will make it easier because then SpotBugs can pick up all the classpath configuration and whatnot from Gradle.  It was very easy to add SpotBugs to Gradle, and now I can run the corresponding SpotBugs task from Gradle and it produces reports in XML files.

The missing piece is that I would like to view the resulting errors/warnings/problems in IntelliJ.  There is a SpotBugs plugin for IntelliJ, but it doesn't seem to know anything about Gradle.  When I ask the SpotBugs plugin to analyze a module, it says the module is not compiled and doesn't report any issues.  (But there are classfiles under the `build` directory (created by Gradle I think) as well as under the `out` directory (created by IntelliJ).)

How to run SpotBugs with the configuration specified by Gradle, while viewing the results in a nice IntelliJ window?

Some background:

Different team members use different IDEs, and we would like to make sure that everyone fixes certain warnings to keep the code quality high.  I've looked into configuring the IntelliJ "analysis" settings to match the Eclipse compiler warnings, but it's going to be a slog.  (We also have different subprojects with different warning settings.). So I thought it would be helpful to have an external tool that everyone can run from Gradle, and if that tool says green, then it's green.  Each developer can then configure their IDE settings to their liking, but it will be easy for them to run their code through this external tool (here: SpotBugs) to confirm that all is well.

Comment: I suppose checking "Run using gradle" under **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle** should help. But I'm not sure I fully got your situation, so is it possible to share a sample "HelloWorld" project where I can test my thoughts?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov, thank you for the suggestion.  I haven't tried it, but I guess that this will tell Gradle to run the task, and the task will write an XML report.  My problem is that I would like to see this XML report in the UI of the SpotBugs plug-in.  Yes, I can ask the plug-in to open the report file, but the user experience of this process is meh.